# How to use ternary operator for returning jsx using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to return jsx based on condition using ternary operator.

what i am trying to do?
If admin variable is

```
true then display text "hello i am admin"
false then display text "hello i am normal user"
```

i have the below code to do so

```
function Text({is_admin}: Props) {
    return is_admin ? (
        <span>Hello i am admin</span>) : (
            <span>Hello i am normal user </span>)
    );
}
```

this code works. now i want to add another condition

if `is_admin` is true and has `count` < 0 display text "not visible user" and do not display text "hello i am admin"

and text "hello i am normal user" will be displayed if `is_admin` is `false`

how can i modify the above code to fit these conditions. could someone help me with this? thanks.

Comment: What if `count > 0`? what will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could nest ternary condition, but this is not recommended because it's considered tough to read.

I would recommend something like this

```
function Text({is_admin, count}: Props) {
  if (is_admin) {
    return count < 0 ? <span>not visible user</span> : <span>Hello i am admin</span>
  }

  return <span>Hello i am normal user </span>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having deeply nested ternary operations, you can simplify the component by utilising early returns.

This will reduce the need to implement nested `if..else`/ternary operator statements. In addition, it is much more readable.

```
// not admin   
if (!is_admin) {
  return <span>Hello i am normal user </span>;
}

// admin, count < 0
if (count < 0) {
  return <span>not visible user</span>;
}

// admin, count > 0
if (count > 0) {
  return <span>Hello i am admin</span>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain those ternary operations *ad infinitum*.

```
function Text({ is_admin }: Props) {
    const count = ...;
    return is_admin
            ? count < 0
                ? (<span>Not visible user</span>) 
                : (<span>Hello i am admin</span>) 
            : (<span>Hello i am normal user </span>));
}
```

This is something to think about to avoid due to readability, though.

Hope it helps.